# Why does Gmail go bonkers once Modernizr is dynamically loaded in it?

Tags: javascript, webkit, gmail, modernizr

Entering this into the Chrome or Safari inspector console, inside Gmail:

```
function load(url,cb){var x=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));x.src=url;x.onload=function(){console.log("Dynamically loaded "+url);if(cb){cb();}};if(!cb){x.setAttribute('async','')}}
load("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js",function(){alert("Modernizr loaded");});
```

Causes the layout of much of the text to go crazy.

Can this be explained? I'd like for my tool (which involves running a bookmarklet which dynamically loads Modernizr) to work on Gmail.

Comment: lol... define bonkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizer adds a lot of classes to the `<html>` tag, and one of those classes is `js`.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation that describes what that represents, although I suspect it just represents JavaScript support.  Google has minified their classes, so they are all short two letter items (probably generated).  One of them happens to be `js` as well, which is causing a lot of text to get centered.

In fact, to un-hose it, just remove the `js` class from the `<html>` tag after dynamically loading your script and it fixes itself.

Here's a fixed version:

```
function load(url,cb){var x=document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));x.src=url;x.onload=function(){console.log("Dynamically loaded "+url);if(cb){cb();}};if(!cb){x.setAttribute('async','')}}
load("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js",function(){var htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; htmlElement.className = htmlElement.className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)js(?!\S)/g , '' );    alert("Modernizr loaded");});
```